Can't force-unwrap inside of a sheet
I've created a simple example that's crashing my previews.
The code below crashes when the text is tapped, with the error saying that it found nil when trying to force unwrap itemToShow.
This doesn't make sense to me since the code assigns itemToShow to a non-nil value before showing the sheet with showSheet = true.
struct TestView: View {
    
    @State var showSheet = false
    @State var itemToShow: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Show sheet")
            .onTapGesture {
                itemToShow = "Apple"
                showSheet = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                Text(itemToShow!)
            }
    }
}


I'm guessing this has something to do with how SwiftUI updates views, but why is this error happening?

Are you aware of .sheet(item: $itemToShow) { Text($0) }? showSheet is redundant here.

@Sweeper thanks for pointing that out, I'm aware but this is a just a simple example for my curiosity for why it won't work

Well you asked "what's a possible fix", and that is a possible fix. If that doesn't apply to your specific case, you should [edit] and show a more relevant example.

It is not the unwrapping that is the problem.
You have to capture the variable itemToShow, so you can use it in the closure.
For example:
.sheet(isPresented: $showFullNew) { [itemToShow] in             Text(itemToShow!)  }
